# Option values hidden if present in database

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script that will check the database and not display option values if they are already present in the database but im not sure how to go about it. Below is what I have so far. Any help would be apprcaited. I've looked though several similar topics on here but they did not really fit what I was looking to do. I also put an example table below to better explain what im looking for. So if a pseron have flag 2 and 3 assigned to them only option 1 will be visable.

```
<?php
                $flag["infractions"] = [];
                $sql = "SELECT *
FROM flag_info
INNER JOIN infraction_flags 
ON flag_info.flag_id = infraction_flags.flag_id
WHERE ban_id = ?;";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $banId);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                if ($result->num_rows != 0)
                {
                    echo "<table width='85%'>";
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $id = $row['flag_id'];
                        $longName = $row['flag_long_name'];
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo $longName . "&nbsp";
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<form action='includes/deleteFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "'>";
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='flag_id' value='" . $id . "'>";
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='[X]'></td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "</form>";
                echo "<hr>";
                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM flag_info";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                echo "<form action='includes/assignFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
                echo "<select name='flag_id'>";
                while ($flg = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {   
                    if ($flg['flag_id'] = $id) {   //This is the logic to display the option values                 
                     echo "<option value='" . $flg['flag_id'] . "'>" . $flg['flag_long_name'] . "</option>";   
                }
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "' size='1'>";
                echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
                echo "</form>";
```

**infraction_flags table**

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| id     | ban_id | flag_id |
+========+========+=========+
|1       | 15     | 3       |
+--------+--------+---------+ 
|2       | 15     | 2       |
+--------+--------+---------+
|3       | 3      | 1       |
+--------+--------+---------+  
|4       | 1      | 1       |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get all the ID and put into an array.
see `$flag_ids` I've put in your code.
and make implode it to make it like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...
then now select your flag and filter using WHERE NOT IN

OPTION 1

```
<?php

$flag["infractions"] = [];
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM flag_info
INNER JOIN infraction_flags 
ON flag_info.flag_id = infraction_flags.flag_id
WHERE ban_id = ?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $banId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
    $flag_ids = array();
    echo "<table width='85%'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $flag_ids[] = $row['flag_id']; //put all the flag id inside an array
        $longName = $row['flag_long_name'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $longName . "&nbsp";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<form action='includes/deleteFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='flag_id' value='" . $id . "'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='[X]'></td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<hr>";
if(!empty($flag_ids)) {
    $where_in = implode(',', ); //set the array like 1, 2, 3, 4
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM flag_info WHERE flag_id NOT IN(" . $where_in . ")";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo "<form action='includes/assignFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<select name='flag_id'>";
    while ($flg = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $flg['flag_id'] . "'>" . $flg['flag_long_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "' size='1'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

OPTION 2: If you still want to show the select even option is empty

```html
<?php

$flag["infractions"] = [];
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM flag_info
INNER JOIN infraction_flags 
ON flag_info.flag_id = infraction_flags.flag_id
WHERE ban_id = ?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $banId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
    $flag_ids = array();
    echo "<table width='85%'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $flag_ids[] = $row['flag_id']; //put all the flag id inside an array
        $longName = $row['flag_long_name'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $longName . "&nbsp";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<form action='includes/deleteFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='flag_id' value='" . $id . "'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='[X]'></td>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<hr>";
$where_in = implode(',', ); //set the array like 1, 2, 3, 4
$where_in = empty($where_in) ? '0' : $where_in;
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM flag_info WHERE flag_id NOT IN(" . $where_in . ")";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
  echo "<form action='includes/assignFlags.inc.php' method='POST'>";
  echo "<select name='flag_id'>";
  while ($flg = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value='" . $flg['flag_id'] . "'>" . $flg['flag_long_name'] . "</option>";
  }
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='ban_id' value='" . $banId . "' size='1'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: So this partially works. However if there are no flags assigned to a specific ban id it will not execute the query correctly and throws a fatal error when its preparing the SQL3 on line 253 below the query string. Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 in G:\xampp\htdocs\highballSystem\details.php:25

Comment: Yup, but you are suppose to fix it. okay let me update the code.

Comment: @David, I have updated the code. give it a shot.

Comment: or you can put 
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

Comment: you just have to analyze it. hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL inner join. And set where condition flag_id = 2 or flag_id = 3